# Can't get image URL with $_GET and display image

Tags: php, url, parameters

I'm trying to use a parameter in the URL to get a Image Path, then display the image on the Website.
I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

URL is like: https://DOMAIN/file.php?logo=https://DOMAIN/IMG/image.png

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="logo">
         <?php $logo = $_GET['logo']; ?>
         <img src="$logo">
     </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried the  (No quotation marks but that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: When you take a look at the generated HTML, what does it look like?

Comment: `<img src="$logo">` is HTML, so `$logo` is never expanded to a value, you are literally making `src` equal to the string `$logo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$logo` is a PHP variable, so if you don't call it in side `<?php ?>` then it will literally print out `<img src="$logo">` in the HTML element.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="logo">
         <?php $logo = $_GET['logo']; ?>
         <img src="<?= $logo ?>">
     </div>
</div>
```

OR:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="logo">
         <?php $logo = $_GET['logo']; ?>
         <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<image src = "<?php echo $logo; ?>">
```

Html doesn't know what is $logo, so you must echo it in src, and html would read the echoed value and display your image

Answer (score 0):

Answers worked perfectly!

Final Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <?php $logo = $_GET['logo']; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>">
    </div>
```